# How do I insert an element directly after another element with XMLStarlet?

Tags: xmlstarlet

With this example XML:

```
<rootnode>
  <element-a />
  <element-b />
  <element-d />
  <element-e />
</rootnode>
```

How do I insert element `<element-c/>` directly after the element `<element-b/>` using XMLStarlet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

xml ed -i (or --insert) will put the it before the node, xml ed -a (or --append) will put it after, so you can use either one of:

```
xml ed -i /rootnode/element-d -t elem -n element-c -v "" file.xml
xml ed -a /rootnode/element-b -t elem -n element-c -v "" file.xml
```